# Why do Sometimes My Emails Not Get Their Address Loaded ?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My app sends out a confirmation email when a customer makes a purchase. 8 / 10 send out fine, but 2 / 10 come back with an error message saying the Email address is missing and no attempt to send could be made.

I have checked the SESSION which provides the email and it appears to work fine.  I was wondering whether there might be something in the config or code which can be tweaked to fix things.

Many Thanks !

Here is my existing config /Code :

```
 <?php

$config['wrapchars'] = '76';
  $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
  $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
  $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
  $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
  $this->email->initialize($config);

  $templates = $this->MEmail->getEmailTemplate('2'); 
  $email = $_SESSION['email'];

  foreach($templates->result() as $row)
  {$message = $row->Contents;
   $templatename = $row->Name;
  }

  $pickupdate = $_POST['pickupdate'];
  $pickuplocation = $_POST['location'];
  $start_time=$data['times']['start_time'];
  $endtime=$data['times']['endtime'];

  $data = array(
               'heading' => 'Country Lane Farms: Your Order Details',
               'message' =>$message,
      'firstname' => $_SESSION['firstname'],
           'lastname' => $_SESSION['lastname'],
      'order_num' => $_SESSION['order_num'],
      'totalprice' => $_SESSION['totalprice'],
      'orders'=> $_SESSION['cart'],
      'pickupdate' => $pickupdate,
      'pickuplocation'=> $pickuplocation,
      'start_time' => $start_time,
      'endtime' => $endtime
          );


   $html = $this->load->view('/templates/confirm_order.php',$data, TRUE);
   $this->email->clear();
   $this->email->from('orderdesk@countrylanefarms.com', 'Country Lane Farms (Jerry)');
   $this->email->to($email);
   $this->email->subject($templatename);
   $this->email->message($html); 
   $this->email->send();

?>
```

Comment: did you call session_start()?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason is session is getting destroy. I suggest to create a TExtFile or database log [anyways you want the log to be] and record the Session Variable in your log, with message of email sent or not. This will tell you what might have happen, Maybe you want to print other variable in log too.